# Не группировать товары в корзине - Wordpress woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Использую магазин на Wordpress woocommerce
При добавлении в корзину нескольких штук одного и того же товара как сделать так, чтобы они не группировались в одну строку в корзине, а отображались разными строками?
У меня в корзине покупатель может отдельно настраивать каждый товар перед покупкой и группировка не нужна.

Вместо этого:
Куртка черная- 3 шт

Нужно что бы было так:

Куртка черная - 1 шт

Куртка черная - 1 шт

Куртка черная - 1 шт

Ссылки на сам магазин нет, поскольку это стандартный магазин woocommerce.

Comment: https://businessbloomer.com/woocommerce-display-separate-cart-items-product-quantity-1/

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/Алексей  - помогло. Спасибо за ссылку

Answer (score 1):

Добавил ответ для тех, у кого такая же проблема :)

```
// 1. Разделить количество товара на несколько товаров в корзине
// Очистите корзину перед тестом.

function bbloomer_split_product_individual_cart_items( $cart_item_data, $product_id ){
  $unique_cart_item_key = uniqid();
  $cart_item_data['unique_key'] = $unique_cart_item_key;
  return $cart_item_data;
}

add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_cart_item_data', 'bbloomer_split_product_individual_cart_items', 10, 2 );

// -------------------
// 2. Отключить кнопки изменения количества
// Товар можно будет добавить несколько раз в корзину

add_filter( 'woocommerce_is_sold_individually', '__return_true' );
```